# HtmlAgilityPack basic how to get title and link?

Tags: html, vb.net, parsing

**Html**

```
<div class="col">                   
<a class="video-box" title="En son haber" href="http://**/en-son-haber">
<img class="img-responsive" alt="en son haber" src="http://**/thumb/6/9/6/200x120/en-son-haber-49-29.jpg"> 
<span class="title">En son haber</span>
<span class="duration">01:02</span><span class="view-count">9.023</span></a>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
 Dim request2 As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://**.com/")
 Dim response2 As HttpWebResponse = request2.GetResponse()
 Dim reader2 As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream())
 Dim sayfa2 As String = reader2.ReadToEnd()
 Dim dokuman2 = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()                         
 dokuman2.LoadHtml(sayfa2)

 Dim getir2 As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = dokuman2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='col']")
 For Each node In getir2             
      TextBox1.Text += node.SelectSingleNode("//a[@class='video-box']").SelectSingleNode("href").InnerText 
 Next
```

I want get `link` and `title` in a `div` but `SelectSingleNode` retrieving duplicate value..

How to get true.

Comment: Using HtmlAgilityPack lib is a necessary requisite? I can give you a solution using Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the examples page http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples, the very first example shows how to access attributes..

so in your case

```
 For Each node In getir2   
      dim aTag as HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode = node.SelectSingleNode("//a[@class='video-box']")
      TextBox1.Text += aTag["href"].value
      'and for the title
      TextBox1.Text += aTag["title"].value
 Next
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct usage:

```
TextBox1.Text &= node.SelectSingleNode("//a[@class='video-box']").Attributes("title").Value
TextBox1.Text &= node.SelectSingleNode("//a[@class='video-box']").Attributes("href").Value
```

Comment: Hey, what about me for making a bounty for a unknown person? :P   @dotNET thanks for the solution.