# Retrieve attributes and span using HTMLAgilityPack library

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

In this piece of HTML code:

```
<div class="item">

    <div class="thumb">
        <a href="http://www.mp3crank.com/wolf-eyes/lower-demos-121866" rel="bookmark" lang="en" title="Wolf Eyes - Lower Demos album downloads">
        <img width="100" height="100" alt="Mp3 downloads Wolf Eyes - Lower Demos" title="Free mp3 downloads Wolf Eyes - Lower Demos" src="http://www.mp3crank.com/cover-album/Wolf-Eyes-–-Lower-Demos.jpg" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="release">
        <h3>Wolf Eyes</h3>
        <h4>
        <a href="http://www.mp3crank.com/wolf-eyes/lower-demos-121866" title="Wolf Eyes - Lower Demos">Lower Demos</a>
        </h4>
        <script src="/ads/button.js"></script>
    </div>

    <div class="release-year">
        <p>Year</p>
        <span>2013</span>
    </div>

    <div class="genre">
        <p>Genre</p>
        <a href="http://www.mp3crank.com/genre/rock" rel="tag">Rock</a>
        <a href="http://www.mp3crank.com/genre/pop" rel="tag">Pop</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

I know how to parse it in other ways, but I would like to retrieve this Info using `HTMLAgilityPack` library:

> ```
> Title : Wolf Eyes - Lower Demos
> Cover : http://www.mp3crank.com/cover-album/Wolf-Eyes-–-Lower-Demos.jpg
> Year  : 2013
> Genres: Rock, Pop
> URL   : http://www.mp3crank.com/wolf-eyes/lower-demos-121866
> ```

Which are these html lines:

```
Title : title="Wolf Eyes - Lower Demos"
Cover : src="http://www.mp3crank.com/cover-album/Wolf-Eyes-–-Lower-Demos.jpg"
Year  : <span>2013</span>
Genre1: <a href="http://www.mp3crank.com/genre/rock" rel="tag">Rock</a>
Genre2: <a href="http://www.mp3crank.com/genre/pop" rel="tag">Pop</a>
URL   : href="http://www.mp3crank.com/wolf-eyes/lower-demos-121866"
```

This is what I'm trying, but I always get an `object reference not set` exception when trying to select a single node,
Sorry but I'm very newbie with HTML, I've tried to follow the steps of this question [HtmlAgilityPack basic how to get title and link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180026/htmlagilitypack-basic-how-to-get-title-and-link)

```
Public Class Form1

    Private htmldoc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    Private htmlnodes As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = Nothing

    Private Title As String = String.Empty
    Private Cover As String = String.Empty
    Private Genres As String() = {String.Empty}
    Private Year As Integer = -0
    Private URL as String = String.Empty

    Private Sub Test() Handles MyBase.Shown

        ' Load the html document.
        htmldoc.LoadHtml(IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\source.html"))

        ' Select the (10 items) nodes.
        htmlnodes = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='item']")

        ' Loop trough the nodes.
        For Each node As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In htmlnodes

            Title = node.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='release']").Attributes("title").Value
            Cover = node.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='thumb']").Attributes("src").Value
            Year = CInt(node.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='release-year']").Attributes("span").Value)
            Genres = ¿select multiple nodes?
            URL = node.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='release']").Attributes("href").Value

        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake here it to try to access an attribute of a childnode from the one you've found.

When you call `node.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='release']")` you get the correct div returned, but calling `.Attributes` returns just the attributes for the `div` tag itself, not any of the inner HTML elements.

It's possible to write XPATH queries that select the sub-node, e.g. `//div[@class='release']/a` - see http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp for more information on XPATH. Although the examples are for XML, most of the principles should apply to a HTML document.

Another approach is to use further XPATH calls on the node you've found. I've amended your code to make it work using this approach:

```
' Load the html document.
htmldoc.LoadHtml(IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\source.html"))

' Select the (10 items) nodes.
htmlnodes = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='item']")

' Loop through the nodes.
For Each node As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In htmlnodes

    Dim releaseNode = node.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='release']")
    'Assumes we find the node and it has a a-tag
    Title = releaseNode.SelectSingleNode(".//a").Attributes("title").Value
    URL = releaseNode.SelectSingleNode(".//a").Attributes("href").Value

    Dim thumbNode = node.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='thumb']")
    Cover = thumbNode.SelectSingleNode(".//img").Attributes("src").Value

    Dim releaseYearNode = node.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='release-year']")
    Year = CInt(releaseYearNode.SelectSingleNode(".//span").InnerText)

    Dim genreNode = node.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='genre']")
    Dim genreLinks = genreNode.SelectNodes(".//a")
    Genres = (From n In genreLinks Select n.InnerText).ToArray()

    Console.WriteLine("Title : {0}", Title)
    Console.WriteLine("Cover : {0}", Cover)
    Console.WriteLine("Year  : {0}", Year)
    Console.WriteLine("Genres: {0}", String.Join(",", Genres))
    Console.WriteLine("URL   : {0}", URL)

Next
```

Note that in this code we're assuming the document is correctly formed and that each node/element/attribute exists and is correct. You might want to add a lot of error checking to this, e.g. `If someNode Is Nothing Then ....`

Edit: I've amended the code above slightly, to ensure each .SelectSingleNode uses the ".//" prefix - this ensures it works if there are several "item" nodes, otherwise it selects the first match *from the document* not the current node.

If you want a shorter XPATH solution, here is the same code using that approach:

```
' Load the html document.
htmldoc.LoadHtml(IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\source.html"))

' Select the (10 items) nodes.
htmlnodes = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='item']")

' Loop through the nodes.
For Each node As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In htmlnodes

    Title = node.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='release']/h4/a[@title]").Attributes("title").Value
    URL = node.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='release']/h4/a[@href]").Attributes("href").Value

    Cover = node.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='thumb']/a/img[@src]").Attributes("src").Value

    Year = CInt(node.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='release-year']/span").InnerText)

    Dim genreLinks = node.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='genre']/a")
    Genres = (From n In genreLinks Select n.InnerText).ToArray()

    Console.WriteLine("Title : {0}", Title)
    Console.WriteLine("Cover : {0}", Cover)
    Console.WriteLine("Year  : {0}", Year)
    Console.WriteLine("Genres: {0}", String.Join(",", Genres))
    Console.WriteLine("URL   : {0}", URL)
    Console.WriteLine()

Next
```

Comment: Thanks, then if I understand good the second code is safer and faster? which I should use? I have 10 item nodes/blocks I mean 10 titles/covers/urls to retrieve

Comment: I am not sure which would be better. The second example requires good knowledge of xpath and is a bit more tightly bound to the HTML structure. For example is the title is changed from a h4 tag to h5, the second example would fail but the first would still work.

Comment: Oh.. if speed is an issue, I'd suggest some experiments on timing - try creating a big html document and use the StopWatch class (in System.Diagnostics) to time these to see which is faster.

Answer (score 1):

You were not that far from the solution. Two important notes:

- `//` is a recursive call. It can have some heavy performance impact, and also it may select nodes you don't want, so I suggest you only use it when the hierarchy is deep or complex or variable, and you don't want to specify the whole path.
- There is a useful helper method on `XmlNode` named `GetAttributeValue` which will you get an attribute even if it does not exist (you need to specify the default value).

Here is a sample that seems to work:

```
' select the base/parent DIV (here we use a discriminant CLASS attribute)
' all select calls below will use this DIV element as a starting point
Dim node As HtmlNode = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='item']")

' get to the A tag which is a child or grand child (//) of a 'release' DIV
Console.WriteLine(("Title :" & node.SelectSingleNode("div[@class='release']//a").GetAttributeValue("title", CStr(Nothing))))

' get to the IMG tag which is a child or grand child (//) of a 'thumb' DIV
Console.WriteLine(("Cover :" & node.SelectSingleNode("div[@class='thumb']//img").GetAttributeValue("src", CStr(Nothing))))

' get to the SPAN tag which is a child or grand child (//) of a 'release-year' DIV
Console.WriteLine(("Year  :" & node.SelectSingleNode("div[@class='release-year']//span").InnerText))

' get all A elements which are child or grand child(//) of a 'genre' DIV
Dim nodes As HtmlNodeCollection = node.SelectNodes("div[@class='genre']//a")
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To nodes.Count - 1
    Console.WriteLine(String.Concat(New Object() { "Genre", (i + 1), ":", nodes.Item(i).InnerText }))
Next i

' get to the A tag which is a child or grand child (//) of a 'release' DIV
Console.WriteLine(("Url   :" & node.SelectSingleNode("div[@class='release']//a").GetAttributeValue("href", CStr(Nothing))))
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the "GetAttributeValue" will save me for empty attributes.